# Is there a way to stop app notifications without going to iPhone settings?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I tried the following code, but it doesn't work. Unless there is a certain place I put it.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cancelAllLocalNotifications` will do just that, cancel all previously scheduled local notifications. It won't turn off the local notification feature for your app, you just have to make sure you cancel all previous ones and don't post new ones. There is no way to turn off that switch in the settings app programmatically.